# DIV equal height, fluid width and various columns

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a product display page. I want my divs to act like the second example from this URL: http://css-tricks.com/examples/FluidEqualHeightFauxColumns/

But the number of divs in the same line might be different each time. And if there are too many divs, those will continue on the next line.

Is it possible to do this without JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">aaaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3aaaaaaa</div>
    <div class="inner">4</div>
<div />

.outer
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px; /* or a fixed width */
}
```

CSS:

```
.inner
{
    float: left;

    /* style as you please */
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the example "css table" work for your need?

Comment: The problem with the "css table" example is that I can't set a specific width. Since the width will depend on the product image and it will never be the same width.

Comment: produce a fiddle and let us play around with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    <div class="inner">4</div>
<div />
```

The CSS:

```
.outer
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%; /* or a fixed width */
}

.inner
{
    float: left;

    /* style as you please */
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}
```

The outer div will adapt its height to the items contained, while the inner items will always maintain their exact size. When the outer div is too small, the inner boxes will flow to a new line. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the height. It's depending on the product image.

Comment: I understand. Without javascript I can't help you out. All I can do is this: show you a page that does something very similar but is probably pretty unrelated. Hope this is a good example of what else you could do: [layout different-height boxes server-side only](https://www.eqnlandmark.com/)

Comment: I figured I could get the image width with PHP (which is safer than JavaScript). When I got the image width, I can figure the div width and therefore your solution works. Thanks!